# Handling DateTime? in NHibernate/LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, datetime, nullable

this is a follow-up to question [Better DateTime? or use default(DateTime) for NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821560/better-datetime-or-use-defaultdatetime-for-null)

I tried to implement a simple query that works with `DateTime?` with a different example rather than the one of the other question.

In my case I have `public virtual DateTime? Expiration` property mapped as

```
<property name="Expiration" not-null="false" type="DateTime" />
```

Now my LINQ query is the following

```
return (from product in session.Query<Product>()
                    where
                        !product.Hidden &&
                        (product.Expiration != null ||
                        (product.Expiration.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays < 5 && (product.Expiration.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays >= 0)
                    select product).ToList();
```

Query says: pick all products that are not hidden and not expiring in 5 days (<5 verify expired products so I have to add the second check)

I get an exception from ANTLR:

```
'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException'. [.Where(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[Model.Product], Quote((product, ) => (AndAlso(Not(product.Hidden), OrElse(DateTime.op_Inequality(product.Expiration, NULL), AndAlso(LessThan(DateTime.op_Subtraction(product.Expiration.Value, p2).TotalDays, p3), GreaterThanOrEqual(DateTime.op_Subtraction(product.Expiration.Value, p4).TotalDays, p5)))))), )]
```

How do I handle a DateTime? in NHibernate 3.0 with LINQ?

Comment: Just found that Expiration!=null is the opposite of what I need (select a product that is NOT set to expire), so don't mind :) it doesn't affect my results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `product.Expiration.Value - DateTime.Now` and also you can't do `(product.Expiration.Value - DateTime.Now).TotalDays` because there is no support for this functions in nhibernate2linq (I don't know , in Entity Framework you can use them by [canonical entity functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but I don't know about nhibernate3 may be they fix them, just one thing you can create a wrapper for your actions :)

Comment: Yea, I already did a workaround. I first select all results from DB (fortunately, they are not many in this case) and then re-query the resulting list against my timestamp criteria

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you posted the actual exception, but my guess is that `.TotalDays` is not being mapped to SQL.

When writing server-side LINQ queries, keep in mind that not every operation can be converted to a SQL call, **only those that have been explicitly covered**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use variables instead of direct DateTime calling. It can be a reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This is a piece of my Linq over Nhibernate 3.0 query

```
.Where(c => c.EndDate.Value >= DateTime.Now && c.BeginDate.Value <= DateTime.Now)
```

What I found out, that this piece gets transformed to

```
and session2_.LCSE_END_DATE >= '26.02.YYYY 09:34:12' 
and session2_.LCSE_BEGIN_DATE <= '26.02.YYYY 09:34:12')
```

It seems like that he is not able to transform correctly DateTime.Now! Might be a bug??

Answer (score 0):

Hallo 
I found actually my problem, which seems not related with NHibernate Linq. I got confused, because Nhibernate profiler showed the following query to be executed on the DB

```
and session2_.LCSE_END_DATE >= '26.02.YYYY 09:34:12' 
and session2_.LCSE_BEGIN_DATE <= '26.02.YYYY 09:34:12')
```

Finally, I suppose it is a bug of NhibernateProfiler.

Comment: It is. Or, better, it's the fact that a **complete** NHibernate to LINQ provider will never exist, as told me by one of the developers I recently met in Milan